# journal_id field in account.payment is not getting override in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to change the **domain filter** of **journal_id** field which is currently **[('type', 'in', ('bank', 'cash'))]** this. I wanna apply only **[('type', '=', 'cash')]**. But its not changing while I am trying to override it.

1. I applied xpath and replace it with my custom domain
2. I created the field again and applied the domain but thats too not giving me the proper result

   `<xpath expr="//field[@name='journal_id']" position="after">
       <field name="journal_id" widget="selection" 
       domain=" [('employee_id.user_id','=',uid)]"/>
   <xpath/>`

or

```
`<field name="journal_id" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="domain">[('type','=',cash)]</attribute>
   </field>
```

I want to show only those journal in drop down whose type is **'cash'**

Please help out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function which is setting domain in payment and you have to find that function and override it according to your requirement.

Comment: It worked..!! There was a onchange function in payment in which domain was defined. Thanks a lot.